# Is there any possibility to have an overflow that works but not visible?

Tags: html, css, overflow, invisible

I am just wondering if there is any solution for a scrollable area (ie `overflow: scroll`) with the scrollbar hidden? I didn't find a solution while googling it so i ask here. It would be cool if this is possible with CSS. But if there is a solution with JS or php I'd still like to know.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Please elaborate.

Comment: Are you asking about hiding scrollbars but still being able to scroll?

Comment: They all work, according to spec that is. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you dont see the scrollbar but it works. So that you dont have the ugly bar in the right but you are still able to scroll? Do you get it know? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By absolute positioning a `container` in an outer container that is relative positioned with hidden overflow you can hide the scrollbar of the inner container outside of the first.

So the scrollbar is still there, but you won't be able to see it.

```
    #outer {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #inner {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: -30px;
        bottom: 0;  
        padding-right: 15px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/g6URf/